# Add a free product if it is already in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I use a code that adds a free product to the cart if the total is equal to or greater than 1500. If the total is less than 1500, then the product is removed.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_free_product_to_cart' );
function add_free_product_to_cart( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Settings
    $minimum_amount   = 1500;
    $free_product_id  = 290;

    // Initializing
    $cart_subtotal = 0;
    $cart_items    = $cart->get_cart();

    // Loop through cart items (first loop)
    foreach ( $cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){
        // When free productis is cart
        if ( $cart_item['data']->get_id() == $free_product_id ) {
            $free_item_key = $cart_item_key; // Free product found (get its cart item key)

            $cart_item['data']->set_price(0);
        }
        // Get cart subtotal incl. tax and discounts (excluding free product)
        else {
            $cart_subtotal += $cart_item['line_total'] + $cart_item['line_tax'];
        }
    }

    // When cart total is up to the minimum amount, add the free product if not already there
    if ( $cart_subtotal >= $minimum_amount && ! isset($free_item_key) ) {
        $cart_item_key = $cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );

        // display notice after removal
        wc_add_notice( __("Thank you! Here's your free product."), 'notice' );
    }
    // if below the minimum, remove the free product
    elseif ( $cart_subtotal < $minimum_amount && isset( $free_item_key ) ) {

        $cart->remove_cart_item( $free_item_key );

        // display notice after removal
        wc_add_notice( sprintf(
           __("Your cart subtotal is less than %s and therefore, the free product was removed."), wc_price($cart_subtotal)
        ), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

The code works, just one problem. When this product is added to cart by a customer, this product is not added.

How can I make this product be added to cart and if the amount is 1500 or more, then the second free product is added to the first product? As a result, there should be two products with ID 290. The first with a regular price, the second with zero price.

I'll be glad you helped!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the answer you're looking for, BUT...

Would you not prefer having some sort of message clearly indicating to the customer (with more than 1500 in cart) that they are entitled to a free product?

Then you can simply point them to the product page with another message (triggered if cart over 1500) that this product will be free if added to cart.

That way, it fixes your issue and if someone does NOT want the free product, you will not "throw" one away automatically.

It's just my two cents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This variant is not suitable.

Comment: Do you see "Your cart subtotal is less than %s and therefore, the free product was removed" when you add product AND cart total <1500 ? (The scenario, you say product is never added (?))